# Uncertainty of a Mean from measurements with different uncertainties and of different items

Tags: mean, standard-error, measurement-error, error-propagation

I've searched around, but I am just not sure that the explanations I've found quite match up with what I am trying to do. Let's say I have 3 vials of a gas. For each vial, I measure some $T$, $P$, and $L$ once each. So I have one measurement for $T$ for each vial, one measurement of $P$ for each vial, and one measurement of $L$ for each vial.

I know that each measurement of $T$, $P$, and $L$ has an associated uncertainty $\sigma_T$, $\sigma_P$, $\sigma_L$ which is known exactly. I therefore know, for example, that the gas in vial 1 has $T_1\pm\sigma_{T}$ and in vial 2 we have $T_2\pm\sigma_{T}$.

Now there is a quantity, $M=TPL$, for which I desire to know the mean value, $\bar{M}$. To do this, I first calculate $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$, for the respective vials. The associated uncertainty in these values is determined from the "propagation of error formula" as
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{M_i}^2 &= \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)^2_i\sigma_T^2+\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial P}\right)^2_i\sigma_P^2+\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial L}\right)^2_i\sigma_L^2\\
\\
\sigma_{M_i} &= M_i\left(\frac{\sigma_T^2}{T_i^2}+\frac{\sigma_P^2}{P_i^2}+\frac{\sigma_L^2}{L_i^2}\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
$$
So each of my three values for $M_i$ will have a different uncertainty.

This is where I get confused. What I am doing now is calculating the mean as $\bar{M} = \frac{1}{3}(M_1+M_2+M_3)$ and then the uncertainty on the mean is just
$$
\sigma_{\bar{M}} = s_{{M}}/\sqrt{3},
$$
where $s_{{M}}$ is the standard deviation of $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$.

However, it feels like I should use the propagation of error formula on the equation for the mean since the uncertainties on each $M_i$ are not the same and they are coming from different vials. So I'm thinking I should do

$$
\sigma_{\bar{M}}^2 = \frac{1}{3^2}(\sigma_{M_1}^2+\sigma_{M_2}^2+\sigma_{M_3}^2),
$$
where if each $\sigma_{M_i}$ were the same, that is, $\sigma_{M_i} = \sigma_M$, I would get the formula I am currently using but with $\sigma_M$ instead of $s_M$

Do I have it right already, or should I change to this second method? I feel like the second method makes the most sense because the vials are different. It's unlike other examples where the repeated measurements are done on the same item. This is several measurements but only one each from several items and so the uncertainties in each $M_i$ are different. If it were 3 measurements on the same vial, I would simply use $\sigma_{\bar{M}} = s_{{M}}/\sqrt{3}$ for the uncertainty on the mean.